# How can i use getpixel to create new image from a pictureBox.Image and a Bitmap bmp?

Tags: c#

Im trying to use Graphics.DrawImage but im getting black image and on it the red points im drawing. Why im getting the black image ?

This is the function:

```
public Bitmap SaveFromPictureBoxToBitMap(Bitmap image1, Image pbox)
        {

            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image1);
            Point p = new Point(pbox.Width,pbox.Height);
            g.DrawImage(pbox, p);
            image1.Save(@"d:\PictureBoxToBitmap\ptob.bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
            return newImage;
        }
```

image1 is the bmp variable wich im drawing to in the paint event. And pbox is just pictureBox1.Image and im using this function in the trackBar1 scroll event.

This is what im getting im adding a screenshot here:

[image]

On the background instead black i need to get the image from the pictureBox1 but it dosent work why ?

Comment: Why don't you just set a `Bitmap` to an of the `PictureBox.Image` property and draw on it without using the additional bitmap? I also wonder why you want to copy the image before saving it. Moreover, you can copy bitmap by writing `newImage = new Bitmap(image2);` and the rest of the code in`SaveFromPictureBoxToBitMap` method is not needed then.

Comment: Sorry, I can't stay longer to look at this.  This probably isn't the root cause of your issue, but could be an issue to resolve nonetheless. In your `SaveFromPictureBoxToBitMap` method, you assign `newColor` twice but only use the second value for it.

Comment: By writing you're getting half of the image you mean you get an image in smaller size (i.e. half of the height of original one) or that you get only image from picturebox without the additional layer from the `bmp`? The latter seems to occur, as you use only pixel color from `picturebox1`. If you want to mix the two images you should check out `Graphics.DrawImage` method.

Comment: You might also want to check out the WriteableBitmapExtensions library.  It may have some functions that you might find useful. http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/

Comment: You might want to look at Graphics.DrawImage and it's overloads, you are reinventing a lot of slow and not particaularly round wheels here.

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```
using (Bitmap b = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height))
{
    pictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(b, new Rectangle(0, 0, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height));
    b.Save(@"d:\testit.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
}
```